# Date Validation - Working Days

Tags: 2010

We have a system where users can submit requests, but we would like to restrict the date so they can only choose a final date that is greater than 2 working days (greater or equal to 3 working days).

```
=OR([Requested Go Live Date]>=TODAY()+3,Created<TODAY())
```

I have been using the above so far, but it does not take into account the weekend.

Would anyone know how to expand on what I have, or would I need to create a new formula entirely?

Comment: You have to use the ''WEEKDAY'' function to add conditions based on todays day